# Try Ubuntu - Where does it store my files?

Tags: files, storage

I am wondering, when you select the option of just "Try Ubuntu" instead of installing, where does Ubuntu store the files that you download / copy / save?

I right click in the Home folder, and it specified I had 4GB free space. Where did it get this 4GB space from, and if I transition to another OS system, how can I access or delete all the previous data from the session of "Try Ubuntu"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Nowhere.

Files are stored on memory and will be deleted when you restart your computer.

If you are using an Live USB, instead of a LiveCD-DVD, when you create it there is an option to make a "persistent" drive. If you check it, your files will be saved to the USB memory.

Comment: Hmm ok, so when I use a Live CD/DVD it store it in the RAM? Then when I shut down the Live Session, those files are no longer retrievable anyway?

Comment: Where the files are stored temporarly?  I am sure that it is not in ram

Comment: Yes, they are usually stored in RAM. If the LiveCD detects a swap partition, it will use it, so in that case, the files or parts of them could be stored in the swap partition.